# How do I serve static content on same domain as WordPress

Tags: directory

I have a portfolio site that I would also like to make a demo site for some of my client work. Basically, I would like to serve a subfolder statically along side the WordPress install. For instance, if I have `http://example.com/demo/subfolder/index.html` that index file would be served directly from Apache rather than WordPress. I have root access to my server, just not sure how to implement this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the files are static HTML, then you only need to be concerned with name collisions for the directory structure. And if you don't have anything in WordPress that generates /demo/subfolder/ you don't have to worry about ignoring it - it's already ignored.

I have a sandbox folder that I use for a similar purpose as you and haven't had to implement anything - It's ignored by WordPress already.

Comment: Old question but search broughrt me here. I get 'Forbidden' if I try to access anything in the subfolder!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the same question, you can use my plugin available at Wordpress repository: [WP Custom HTML Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-html-pages/)

It allows you to serve static HTML pages at custom URI of your choice.

1) Install and activate the plugin

2) Use the new submenu item (Pages->HTML Pages) to create a new HTML page

3) In "Page Permalink" field enter the custom URI you wish to assign to your page, for example /my-html-page (at the time of writing this answer, it is required that the value you enter starts with "/" character) and in "HTML Page Code" field enter all the HTML and CSS of the page document that you wish to display

4) Click "Publish" then go to yourwebsite.com/my-html-page and you should see your static HTML page, providing its status is set to "published"

By creating and linking several pages you may have a whole static website.

Answer (score 0):

You can request WordPress to ignore the subdirectory structure by adding these rules in .htaccess. Add them within `<Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>` But generally if there is no page such as demo, WordPress ignores it and the static page is rendered.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Demo_directory/(.*)$
```

Comment: where? top, middle, bottom